# difference between rest parameters

Tags: node.js, rest, swagger, openapi

I tied to design an API documentation for my rest API based on [[OAS]](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.0.md#parameterObject) there are only 4 parameters that can pass through `in` the field which indicating parameters location.
but in the code I get parameters like below :

```
req.body
```

now it shouldn't have the `body` field? 
what should write instead `body` 
what is different between `query`, `path`, and the `cookie` ?